# How to write JOLT Spec for nested arrays? newbie here

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jolt

i am really newbie on Jolt and try to solve this:

**input JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 528356,
    "version": 0,
    "name": "ActiveMQ",
    "nameUnique": true,
    "config": {
      "id": 528356,
      "version": 0,
      "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE_COLLECTION",
      "name": "ActiveMQ",
      "description": "Default Config",
      "enabled": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2638137,
          "version": 0,
          "jmxCollectionId": 528356,
          "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE",
          "name": "ActiveMQ_Brokers",
          "exclude": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "metricCategory": "Broker",
          "instanceIdentifier": "BrokerName"
        },
        {
          "id": 2638138,
          "version": 0,
          "jmxCollectionId": 528356,
          "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE",
          "name": "ActiveMQ_Queues",
          "exclude": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "metricCategory": "Queues",
          "instanceIdentifier": "Destination"
        },
        {
          "id": 2638139,
          "version": 0,
          "jmxCollectionId": 528356,
          "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE",
          "name": "ActiveMQ_Topics",
          "exclude": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "metricCategory": "Topics",
          "instanceIdentifier": "Destination"
        }
      ],
      "applicationId": 46546
    },
    "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE_COLLECTION"
  },
  {
    "id": 528358,
    "version": 0,
    "name": "Coherence",
    "nameUnique": true,
    "config": {
      "id": 528358,
      "version": 0,
      "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE_COLLECTION",
      "name": "Coherence",
      "description": "Default Config",
      "enabled": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 2638146,
          "version": 0,
          "jmxCollectionId": 528358,
          "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE",
          "name": "Coherence_Caches",
          "exclude": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "metricCategory": "Coherence|Cache Maps",
          "instanceIdentifier": "service,name,nodeId"
        },
        {
          "id": 2638147,
          "version": 0,
          "jmxCollectionId": 528358,
          "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE",
          "name": "Coherence_Cluster",
          "exclude": false,
          "enabled": true,
          "metricCategory": "Coherence|Cluster",
          "instanceIdentifier": null
        }
      ],
      "applicationId": 46546
    },
    "type": "JMX_METRIC_RULE_COLLECTION"
  }
]
```

**Desired output** :

```json
[
  {
    "name": "ActiveMQ",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "ActiveMQ_Brokers"
      },
      {
        "name": "ActiveMQ_Queues"
      },
      {
        "name": "ActiveMQ_Topics"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Coherence",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Coherence_Caches"
      },
      {
        "name": "Coherence_Cluster"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

at the moment, just able to get something using **spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "config": {
          "name": "[].parent",
          "children": {
            "*": {
              "name": "[].child"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current output** :

```json
[
  {
    "parent": "ActiveMQ"
  },
  {
    "child": "ActiveMQ_Brokers"
  },
  {
    "child": "ActiveMQ_Queues"
  },
  {
    "child": "ActiveMQ_Topics"
  },
  {
    "parent": "Coherence"
  },
  {
    "child": "Coherence_Caches"
  },
  {
    "child": "Coherence_Cluster"
  }
]
```

in short, did not find a way to correctly map using keys.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to unite the result at some levels of nodes such like in the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {  
        "config": {
          "name": "[&2].&", //"[&2]" stands for reaching the indexes at uppermost level, "&" copies the literal "name" as attribute's key name.
          "children": {
            "*": {
              "name": "[&4].&2[&1].&" //"[&4]" is needed to traverse two more levels to reach the same level what the above attribute("config.name") needs, "&2" copies the literal "children" after going two levels up the tree, "[&1]" is sub-indexes of it, "&" copies the literal "name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks works like a charm. did not know (yet) it was possible to combine "&" levels